# How to train web speech recognition?

Tags: javascript, html, speech

I am new to speech recognition. I am trying to develop a simple voice based (using HTML 5 & JS) web application (with recognition and utterance ) for my project.

I could see that (tested in chrome) the application does not recognize local words (like some Indian names and places). How can I train the system to make it recognize those words ? Or is there a dictionary kind of file to which I can add these words manually ? Since this is a local application, I cant use cloud Machine Learning for this. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Please share your code to debug easily

Comment: The Web Speech API is still extremely experimental and does not seem to support any sort of training at this time. You can [specify the language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/lang) which might help.

Comment: Thank you for the input @MikeC ! Other possible alternative would be to use cmusphinx, where we have options to train our system!!

Comment: The web speech API is improving, recognizing local place names and people. This may have to do with a message that popped up while playing with a new phone installing their Google App (handles voice, keyboard, and a bunch of other stuff on not-so-ancient phones). The message asked if we wanted to improve recognition by reading the documents we publish in Google Docs to learn about our speech habits. The strange, or maybe not so strange, is it works on any device, including the embedded Web Speech API when using Chrome browsers, but only when signed in to Google. Wish there was more info.

Comment: Are we there yet?